# Choose different background image for iPhone and iPad launch screen

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad

I built an iPhone app whose background image fit nicely for iPhone screens, but when I run at iPad, this image stretch horizontally (as the iPad screen is more squared than the iPhone).

Is there a way for me to choose which background image is going to be loaded?

I know that I can use `UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone` and
`UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad` to check which device I'm in but how can I choose the correct image if Launch Screen doesn't accept code attached to it?

Comment: Use a launch storyboard, not a launch image. Then you can use size classes to adapt the scene presentation. You can’t use code since the launch image is shown before your app starts executing.

Comment: I'm using LaunchScreen.storyboard ... but I didn't get these "size classes"... what is this?

Comment: In Xcode 9 it is under “vary for traits”

Comment: well, I can't see anything under vary for traits, but I didn't understand the first comment anyway... I have three components at LaunchScreen.storyboard viewcontroller, one of them is the background imageView, that I want to be able to choose an image for iphone and another for ipad...

Comment: In your launch storyboard scene you would need to add multiple image views and have one of them installed for "Regular width/Regular Height" (which is the traits for an iPad) and one for other size classes.  In Interface Builder you select "View as..." in the bottom border to vary your scene for different size classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to do this that I can think of is to have two devices in your image set of located in your `Assest.xcassets`. Then assign different images as you like in the two devices, iPhone and iPad, like so:

[image]

Then here's the preview when you run the app on the iPhone (left), and on the iPad (right). Two different images in each kind of device.

[image]

Comment: What about iPad alone supports both orientation?

Answer (score 3):

In your LaunchScreen.storyboard file, you likely have a UIImageView that contains your image. When you click on that image view, you will see details of the view in right slider view. Set the view's content mode to "center" and you will be all set. You can also use "aspect fit" or "aspect fill" if center doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: I can't accept as answer cos it doesn't answer what I asked (that is to load different images), but it's a good tip